# jQuery; Parallax page - Get the click event go through DIV layers

Tags: jquery, layer, mouseclick-event, parallax

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/h87DK/4/)

*The idea* now is to (instead of transp. .png images) fill the layers with standard HTML elements,
like making a nice moving 2d-3d page.

You can guess my first problem.
Whatever I tried I cannot make the click event go through the 100x100% div layers to find  **a clickable (or else?) element that is not the .layer himself.**

Maybe making the layers `height:0px; position:absolute;` and than appending to them relative positioned elements?

Comment: Blender, in terms of design, speed, usability and so on I TOTALLY agree! But making just part of a site (1/4, 1/2 ;) ) in a parallax style... I think some clients would be impressed, and the users too, if created in a gentle/non-aggressive manner. ? agree?

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment. Your parallax is a bit too glidy, I've noticed. GitHub uses parallax with Octocat in their `404` page, and that one moves quite fluidly IMO. Maybe you could look at that one too: https://github.com/asdasdasds

Comment: Blender... try to set in my script `sensitivity` to `1`. Is now better? Or what you mean by saying 'too glidy' ??

Comment: Ahh yes, much better. It felt a bit unresponsive, as it animated for a half a second after I stopped moving the mouse. Nice job!

Comment: thanks! I added the *sensitivity* 'cause if you use it for images (rather than HTML elements) it's a nice feel seeing it 'slow down'! Of course, now using DIVS i'll use sensitivity set to '1'.  Do you have a better name to call this effect? (I used here the Zeno's paradox effect to achieve this 'infinite' slowdowns.)

Comment: I don't really know. Maybe `responsiveness`? It seems like a fine name to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a `z-index` CSS property to the `.box` elements. The higher the `z-index`, the higher the elements appear in terms of layers (i.e. elements with a `z-index` of `999` will be abover those with a `z-index` of `1`):

```
.box {
  ...

  z-index: 2;
}
```

[And a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/h87DK/5/)

Comment: Blender????????? that was.... ARRRRRRGH! I thought that was a z-index answer, as I edited in my question. Well GREAT for getting it work before me! THANKS SO MANY MANY MANY 8) kisses'n'hugs!

Comment: You're welcome. You *did* come up with the solution on your question.